# I didn't know the yellow ax question had been locked. Did you?

Tags: discussion, question-closure, moderators, locked-question

### [Which word begins with "y" and looks like an axe in this picture?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture)

Apparently, the question no longer deserves to be open and was locked on **January 9, 2018**. Is this a surprise for anyone? Maybe a discussion was held somewhere, maybe on meta, maybe on chat? I don't remember seeing it. Can someone post me the link, please?

A question which was **upvoted 440 times**. An answer that was **upvoted** an incredible, and jaw-dropping **837 times**. (I'm counting all the upvotes)

The question, posted on June 23 2017, and  **visited 91,835 times** is now locked. Seemingly, forever.  No one can ever upvote or downvote any post.

I really don't recall any ballyhoo about the quality of the answers posted, but there were a few users who sustained the question was off topic but ***it was never closed by the community***. **Never**. Despite the thousands of visitors and the hundreds of votes cast.

Does the community realise that the question, one day, can now be silently deleted without anyone being consulted? Without anyone knowing.

We should have a discussion, there **should be greater transparency** between users and elected mods. I would like to hear if there are users who support locking this question, and perhaps, one day look forward to seeing it being deleted.

It's been pointed out, in the comments below, that locking a question is not the antechamber leading to its deletion. However, if a question is locked because it does not comply with ELU"s standards then it stands to reason that it's more likely to be deleted in the future despite the considerable attention and votes it attracted.

In fact, [popular questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/deleted-upvoted-and-popular-question-why) with good answers have been silently deleted in the past.  In addition, I submit the following observation where a respected user is undecided which disturbs him the most…

> (b) that a question '**not** [...] **an ELU level question** [, and ...] **not answered by English**, but by contacting certain people about a toy ball' [and not appropriate on ELL either] **took so long to be deleted**. 
>   (c) that the voting system allows such an endorsement of **a question that so clearly violates the intended purpose of ELU**.

I respect this user and his opinion, I appreciate the reasons given for his lack of enthusiasm but would he agree that the question should have been locked or deleted without consulting the community? It's the *second most popular question*, vote-wise, on EL&U. This is the point I am trying to make.

Moreover, it's not just about Dan Bron's answer, some of the other answers on "Y" questions are of a similar high standard. For example, the answers by [Theraot](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/395554/44619), [1006a](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/395595/44619) and [ab2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/395388/44619) were serious attempts at answering the English language question, not about the “toy ball”. Locking the OP hints that Bron's superb research, plus the time and effort spent in crafting his answer should *not* be held as an example of a "high-quality" answer. Did the mod who locked the post consider this aspect?

And finally, the non-native speaker, who posted the question genuinely wanted to know why a child's toy ball had a picture of an ax(e) next to the letter Y.

> Can someone help me identify which English word is depicted in Y?

Can someone please explain why that doesn't qualify as an English *language* question?

**UPDATE**  January 15 2018

> Anything in particular you would like to know via this meta? Is this a call to unlock it? Or just looking for "why" it was locked? Something else? @NVZ

I *was* looking for an explanation as to how the second most popular question (based on the number of upvotes) which  was never closed by the community, that was praised and rewarded by the Stack Exchange team, could suddenly, and inexplicably, be locked from one day to the next without any forewarning. For users who may be interested, please see Andrew Leach's ♦ [comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/i-didnt-know-the-yellow-ax-question-had-been-locked-did-you#comment46777_11106) and tchrists's ♦ closing [knell](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/i-didnt-know-the-yellow-ax-question-had-been-locked-did-you#comment46781_11106).

Comment: I wasn’t aware. Thanks for bringing my attention to it. I’d be interested in MetaEd’s reasoning. I’m not miffed, but I am now curious. Thanks for asking this Q.

Comment: @DanBron so no one even hinted to you that the question could be locked. No one told you before tonight? Allow me to be miffed on your behalf.

Comment: Haha. Thank you for the moral support! I mean it! But I’m a regular user, and the mods are under no obligation to consult me before making mod decisions. And it would be a little ungrateful and precious of me to whine that I won’t be able to earn any more than a measly 837 upvotes ;) (Though I was secretly hoping to see if I could hit the 1K threshold in a year or two.)

Comment: It was a one hit wonder and not really an ELU level question. It's not answered by English, but by contacting certain people about a toy ball. It was fun while it lasted, but not exactly a material that should encourage future visitors to think fits ELU topic.

Comment: Re "Does the community realise that the question, one day, can now be silently deleted without anyone being consulted?" I think nobody can delete a question that has a "[historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)" except moderators (who are always able to delete any question anyway). I would not see this as a step towards deleting the question; in fact, I think it's now more protected from deletion than it was previously.

Comment: Maybe I'm showing my age. But I remember some of the discussions when that question was asked. It seems a bit young to be considered *historical*.

Comment: The question was about English.  (Is there an English word that starts with Y and means the thing in this picture?") The answer did the almost impossible job of proving a negative.  "There is no English word that starts with Y and describes the thing in this picture."  the answer then went on to explain how a Swedish word crept in.  If any future user can write a question which will lead to a comparable level of detective work about English, have at it!  If any future user can come up with an English word that answers that question, I want to hear it.  Protected, sure.  Locked, no.

Comment: I'm not sure which disturbs me most: (a) that 'a question [...] can be silently deleted without anyone being consulted' / (b) that a question 'not [...] an ELU level question [, and ...] not answered by English, but by contacting certain people about a toy ball' [and not appropriate on ELL either] took so long to be deleted / (c) that the voting system allows such an endorsement of a question that so clearly violates the intended purpose of ELU. The question is predicated on a mistake (made by the ball manufacturers) and sensible research is contacting them. It's lit crit, if you like.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth fair enough, I said some users believed that the question was off;topic but the vast majority did not. Let's have this discussion about locking a question that is not even a year old, a question posted when EL&U standards were firmly in place.

Comment: I've said quite often on ELU that voting patterns are sometimes harmful to the site's stature. 'It's actually Elbonian' 837: 'The container metaphor, JL' 7. I love such questions as this, but not on a site aimed at linguists and dedicated to the serious study of the language. If voters can so distort the apparent acceptability of such questions, I've got to say that a college system (uber-policing by an elected panel) is better than a free-for-all, until it itself gets out of hand. I don't think it is near that point yet (though/and I think one 'college member' was reined in a few years back).

Comment: Locking it is not a step closer to deleting it.

Comment: My take on this issue is that the ELU community is not “mature” enough, not yet, to be able to deal with a  question  like this, which, IMHO, don't pose any real threat to the moral integrity of the site. The prevailing idea  that the question would be taken as an exemple by new users to make similar ones is totally unsubstantiated

Comment: @user159691 let's assume out of the bazillion visitors to that question, at least a few would be inspired to ask a similar one. The more visitors the question has, the more likely that there are inspired users. If it was an obscure "tumbleweed" question, locking it would not be necessary; even closing it would not be _that_ necessary seeing that nobody is ever likely to visit it.

Comment: @NVZ - if questions which have  been put on hold have ever been of any guidance to new users, why do we still regularly receive every day more and more off-topic questions by them. I am convinced that the dynamics in play have little if nothing to do with imitation of past questions. That’s my personal opinion of course.

Comment: '[T]he question no longer deserves to be open' is disingenuous. Obviously, a question that is off-topic **never** 'deserved to be open' but cannot be put on hold instantaneously.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but the question was open from June 23, 2017, until January 2018, and during this period it was never put on hold, at the very most it earned a total of four votes in favour of closure. Four, and maybe you voted to close it twice. We get meta posts about deleting a tag that involves ten questions, but nothing is mentioned when such a popualr question gets deleted. Oops, sorry, I meant locked. I don't know, doesn't community consensus represent anything?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Even _if it were_ deleted; the asker or answerers would not lose even 1 rep point. And we ___don't___ delete useful content, even though it's off-topic. That's the very purpose of having historical lock notices. So there's that.

Comment: @NVZ do you really think Dan Bron cares about the rep? Whoever mentioned rep in the first place? And why are you responding when I addressed my comment to Edwin?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm just discussing the subject, and not responding to your comment to anyone in particular.

Answer (score 17):

My thoughts on this...

I had never crossed with a Historical Lock post before, so I firstly tried to understand what it is and what it means.  I found [this reference on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for). The relevant parts of it, IMHO:

> #### What is the purpose of a historical lock?
>
> A historical lock preserves content that was very popular when it was originally posted, but is now off-topic or otherwise out of scope for the site it is posted on.  Historically locking a post ends the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or deleted, and is often the final state of a question that has been deleted and undeleted more than once.

The first sentence above gives two reasons for a post to be historically locked:

1. Very popular when originally posted
2. Now off-topic or otherwise out of scope

The [y-axe question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture) was very popular when originally posted and that's a fact! The 2nd most upvoted in a SE-site with over 90,000 questions and 6 years of age surely qualifies as *being popular*.

About the second point, of the question now being off-topic or out of scope, honestly I don't consider myself qualified to judge that. I'm not much of a contributor here in English SE. Not that many questions or answers. What I can tell is that when I wrote the question it surely was about English Language, after all, I had a ball with 26 pictures with letters and 25 of them were easily recognizable as English words. The ball had no brand, trademarks, nothing that could help me. Stack Exchange is the network I use to solve my questions and English SE seemed like the correct place for it. To imagine that a ball could have 25 English words mixed with a single Swedish one would made me laugh, unless there was a very good, long and detailed detective work, like Dan Bron did. It makes me feel that English SE was the right place to solve that mystery.

Surely the community, high-reps or mods may all have their own opinions on what's on-topic and on-scope for this site and I trust them to do it. If the y-axe question is now considered off-topic, I'm fine with that.

Lastly I would like to thank for the question being historically locked, since this is (as stated earlier) *often the final state of a question*, so it (probably) won't be deleted. Makes me think that if the question was not that popular because of [Dan Bron's brilliant answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/395385/77227), it would be rightfully deleted. So thank you mods, honestly!

Comment: Really, after all we've been together.  Dan Brown?   *[Dan Brown](http://theweek.com/articles/730426/dan-brown-bad-writer)*?  And I thought we had something, you and I :'(

Comment: Oh man...The quality of my readings is decreasing rapidly. From Dan Bron’s superb answer to Dan Brown’s somewhat overrated books! I’ll stop reading his books and read more of your answers! After a Y bugs my life, now a W will do it!

Comment: Hahaha!  Nicely done.  You have redeemed yourself by the grace of a pun.  Please do ask more questions soon!

Comment: @DanBron A wise clown once said, "if you're good at something, never do it for free". You should get hired as a detective sometime. ;)

Comment: There was *no* debate as to whether your question should be left open or closed. None. The question was never deleted and undeleted.  That's the whole purpose of my question on meta.  Saying that, I really admire and respect your gracious acceptance of the "inevitable", but allow me to say and repeat again, your question was on-topic, and it was well crafted, it was not a LQQ. If newcomers are inspired by your question and by Dan Bron's answer it will be for its breadth and detail, not because it was it is a crossword puzzle question. And why nobody supports me on this, baffles me.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  You got support in comments. But I agree that it is puzzling that no one wrote an answer recognizing that the Q was a perfectly good SWR and that the answer was to begin with an outstanding piece of English research and then morphed into a sui generis piece de resistance; the site is better for having it.  (My excuse for not writing an answer is some serious pain from a hip that is due to be replaced.)   Does the comment of sumelic that he thinks a Q under historical lock cannot be deleted give you any comfort?  Is it worth clarifying this via another Meta Q?  If so, I can do.

Comment: @ab2 I appreciate the support and vote of confidence, but when both the author of the question and its answerer have accepted the mod's decision, there is not much more that can be said. Actually, there is a lot more to be said but it's not my battle. I can only voice my dissent.

Answer (score 8):

Just my thoughts...

I'm a big fan of Dan Bron's answer — it's one of a kind, and I've never seen anything like it, and in fact, I think that's the major reason people were interested in the question and how it became a viral hit; a bigger hit than it would have been if it were to hit the HNQ without his answer.

I've voted up the answer *and* the question, and some other answers along the way, and I'm pretty sure others would've voted up the question similarly, and it was a fun read, and there's no denying that a *lot* of people loved reading it all.

But imagine seeing such a question: "what is a word that starts with..." and that it did not reach HNQ or get a Dan Bron-y answer, and ask yourself whether you would have considered it on-topic for ELU.

I think most voters would have closed it, and maybe even said it's like a crossword puzzle that the OP should've asked elsewhere, or that they should contact the manufacturers of the toy ball, who are, in the end, responsible for putting those images against each letter.

Now, about the state of a locked question: being locked is not a step closer to getting it deleted since moderators can delete any content anytime anyway, so having it locked or not, I for one think, is not an issue.

And I'm not *that* convinced about the benefit in having it unlocked and open to new answers, comments or votes: comments would most likely follow the likes of "wow, great, amazing", and a few extra votes coming every now and then, to the already *[idle rich](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10829/50044)* users, probably means nothing, and new answers would probably add nothing new to the page.

The downside of having it stay without a special moderator notice such as the "historical lock" would be that new users would see the question and think of asking something similar, which would not be received similarly well, I think.

Comment: All fair points. +1.

Comment: The OP couldn't contact the ball manufacturer, there was no name printed on the ball. The OP was perplexed and probably thought there was a word beginning with Y that also meant "ax". For a time, I also wondered if that was a possibility.

Comment: @Mari-Lou-A And in fact there was at least one word in an English dictionary beginning with Y for an axe-like object, but  It wasn't suitable for a child's toy.   I think it was yatigan.  A good deal of (not very visible) effort went into proving the negative, before the visible, fun part started.

Comment: Did you ever vote to close it for being off-topic? At the time did you think it was off-topic? Did you think the question was not a good fit for EL&U? (I'm just waiting for an official answer, but these are the questions I would ask them)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I did not at first. See: https://english.stackexchange.com/review/close/241412 But cycles later I did. See: https://english.stackexchange.com/review/close/269658

Comment: Now I get why it was 'suddenly" locked, someone voted to close it on the 6th January, but it passed the review inspection and when it was clear the question was not going to be closed, a mod decided to lock it. Democracy wins, thumbs up!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I just visited the axe question for the first time on the regular, not mobile, site, and the lack of voting arrows looks *so weird*.  Can't they have "ghost" arrows or something? It's so offputting and odd looking.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Anything in particular you would like to know via this meta? Is this a call to unlock it? Or just looking for "why" it was locked? Something else?

Comment: It's a call for clarity, it's a call for openness, it's a call for why was this decision taken single-handedly when the question did not cause controversy. It's call to ask why the question is "now" considered off-topic, but not 8 months ago when the ELUian standards had been pretty much fixed by then.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder what the votes on my answer indicate.

Comment: They indicate that you make valid points.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  Pity those "valid points" were not expressed by the person who undertook that decision, singlehandedly... on a question that did not cause any controversy, on a question that was never closed, that the developers, TPTB of Stack Exchange, thought well to award a special bounty to.  On a question that was posted less than a year ago when the elusive and mercurial standards had been pretty much fixed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm sure it's not a single handed action. If you want it unlocked, I think you should make a stronger case for it. What would the benefit be in having it unlocked?

Comment: I would like a discussion, I would like to know precisely if this decision was taken unanimously or if it was done on a whim, on a caprice because the user disliked the question. Because... questions that have nothing at all to do with the English language are still left open, and the "idle rich" (as you called them) are still reaping their rewards. Call me mad, but I find that terribly unfair.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Moderators discuss; while only one can take any action, because only one vote is necessary, it doesn't mean that it was actually unilateral. It is also the case that moderators deal with flags which users raise drawing matters to their attention. Other users don't get to see those, and it's not usual for such flags to be discussed on Meta prior to taking action. If you would like the lock lifted, please argue why it should be: what is the lock *not* achieving which would be achieved if it were lifted?

Comment: @AndrewLeach there was a flag that specifically asked the mod to lock the question? I don't think that was the request. But it's possible. However, if the question is low-quality, with all those upvotes, you're telling me a newcomer who asks a similar question with tthe same attention to details, the community will automatically reject it? Objectively? I could see it being migrated to ELL but not closed for being off topic. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 But on January 9, it suddenly became off-topic. All this because a newcomer posted a (new) LQA, one mathematician saw it, disliked it and voted to close the question.  But three other experienced users voted to keep it open. Why do you think that happened? Why bother asking users if they agree to keep open or close a question? Let the mods decide for us.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh but that was indeed the exact request in the flag: that an historical lock be applied.  The matter was considered and dispensed with. If every flag is something to be debated on Meta, nothing will ever get done, but it's up to everyone to decide what they think merits community engagement and what merits only a flag.

Comment: @tchrist  The 2nd most popular question and the highest upvoted answer in the history of EL&U did not deserve a listening, a general consensus? A discussion on meta? Well, it took two days but I finally got an answer and an explanation. I suppose the 10 votes that, supposedly, agree with the request for greater transparency count for nothing.

Comment: @tchrist at the very least could you please tell user gmauch that his question is being discussed on meta. I see he is online, but I cannot post a comment or contact him via the apposite chat room because it is frozen. It's absurd that no one can even post a comment or in chat because the question is locked. Can you please tell him? Thank you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm looking at this thread right now. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What is the lock *not* achieving which would be achieved if it were lifted?

Comment: @tchrist The only useful thing a lock prevents is edits fixing broken links etc. A less restrictive lock which prevents new posts, votes, comments, and edits from people less than X rep would probably be better in most circumstances.

Comment: @tchrist `What is the lock not achieving which would be achieved if it were lifted?` it is limiting our freedom of choice, the liberty to cast a vote of preference. How's that? Is that persuasive?

Answer (score 4):

> I didn't know the yellow ax question had been locked. Did you?

Not until I saw this hot meta post, no. Though I'm glad attention has been brought back to it, I've now re-read it and found a lot of DanBron's later research that I previously missed.

> Is this *[the locking as historic]* a surprise for anyone?

It's not particularly surprising, no. I think the original question was valid and interesting, but the answers ended up off-topic (and demonstrating that the question itself was probably off-topic). But as everyone loved it so much, keeping it as historic rather than deleting it seems sensible.

So I'm of the opinion that the best thing has been done. I'm happy with that.