# Can Mods (or anyone) see deleted comments?

Tags: discussion

I tried to look this up on meta, and found no good answer.

If comments have been self-deleted, are they gone forever? And if so...what about all the revisions permitted in the first 4-5 minutes?

Excuse me, I am new to 10K mod privileges, and trying to feel my way around here.

Comment: Diamond mods can, I think. No matter how much rep you get as a non-diamond user, you won’t be able to.

Comment: Technically, for every 1,000 you earn over 25k you get more delete votes or close votes or something, and I think flagging enough gets you more flags (& rep may too), but (a) these are capped to some max, so more rep doesn’t help after some point (say about 40k), & (b) they’re just more of the same powers. The last *new* power you get is at 25k, [and it’s disappointing](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7755/55623). The last new *useful* power you get is at 20k. After that, there’s no advantage to rep for moderation purposes IMO, and it’s pretty useless otherwise (bounties & downvotes).

Comment: Congrats on 10k btw!

Comment: @DanBron there is one extra advantage, when you reach 100K SE's supposed to award you some swag. I read this on [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329051/2019-do-six-figure-reputation-users-on-non-so-sites-still-get-swag). As for comments, nothing is hard deleted, anything can be revived and restored, but if you can't see the "soft" deleted comments or be able to search users' deleted posts, the likelihood of someone, anyone, demanding or asking for its undeletion decreases enormously.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’d forgotten about that! I wonder if Josh ever got his. And I think Sven is in the century club now, too. I cheatily got swag at low rep for the axe question. But here I was focused on the mod powers rep does and doesn’t grant.

Answer (score 4):

[Moderators can see deleted comments.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/)

[Moderators can undelete comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98036/) but **only** if the comment was deleted by a moderator. Moderators cannot undelete comments which the commenter has deleted himself or which have been deleted by flags.

[Moderators can see a comment's revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/184638) for comments edited after October 2012.

These are moderator-only privileges, I'm afraid.

Presumably you have found the [privileges page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and the information on [10k moderator tools](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)? The page is a bit buried, and the tools page even more so.